# I'm getting error "local variable 'form1' referenced before assignment"

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm getting an error

> local variable 'form1' referenced before assignment

This is my `views.py` and I'm unable to figure this out. I am new to Django so can anyone help me with providing a solution and explaining what I am doing wrong.

```
def getview(request):
    formObject = form_input()
    formObject.orign = None
    formObject.destinations = None
    formObject.timeWindow = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formData = ro_input_form(request.POST)

        if formData.is_valid():

            formObject.orign = request.POST.get('orign')
            formObject.destinations = request.POST.get('destinations')
            formObject.timeWindow = request.POST.get('timeWindow')

            formObject.save()

            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        else:

            form1 = ro_input_form()  ## this should be forminput

    return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

This is my models.py:

```
class form_input(models.Model):
   orign = models.TextField(max_length=245,null=True,default='No data')
   destinations = models.TextField(max_length=255,null=True,default='No data')
   timeWindow = models.DateField(max_length=255,null=True,default='No data')
```

This is my forms.py

```
class ro_input_form(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = form_input
      fields = ['orign',
              'destinations',
              'timeWindow',
              ]
```

Comment: declare form1 before if request.method == 'POST 'condition or change name of formData  to form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have passed the form as `form1` as a context in your line:

```
return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

But missed to declare the form with name `form1` inside your `if request.method == 'POST':` block. The solution can be either replace:

```
formData = ro_input_form(request.POST)
```

as

```
form1 = ro_input_form(request.POST)
```

and other places where formData is specified.
Else replace:

```
else:

    form1 = ro_input_form()  ## this should be forminput

return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

As:

```
else:

    formData = ro_input_form()  ## this should be forminput

return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': formData})
```

This causes consistency in the form names.

**Edit:** Trying to fix data not being saved error.

**views.py**

```
def getview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = ro_input_form(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        form1 = ro_input_form()  ## this should be forminput
    return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

**Recommendation:**
As you are using all the fields of your model while declaring the form `ro_input_form`, you can just declare the `fields` in your form as:

```
fields = '__all__'
```

instead of

```
fields = ['orign',
          'destinations',
          'timeWindow',
          ]
```

This is just for easiness. But if you want only specific fields then specifying the fields individually is fine.

Comment: No more error now but it is not saving data into database

Comment: Can you post your models too?

Comment: yes, sure. I've edited my question with models.py and forms.py

Comment: I don't think you need to create a new object for the form_input model in your view as the form is a model form. So just try using `form1.save()` inside your `form.is_valid` block instead. Check if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer for some idea. Do check if that works.

Comment: I used your same views.py code but its still not working. Nothing is migrated even object is not created in database or in admin panel. Any other suggestions.

Comment: Maybe the data is not being properly passed from the template. Can you show your template file?

Comment: I've added the part of template file which is adding the data in html file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189941/discussion-between-sanip-and-chirag-gulati).

Comment: Looking at your template, I think you need to specify the type for your button as <button type="submit">. Using a <button> without a type won't submit your data.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the form1 in html while it's not declared before so you have to declare it before.
You might like to declare form1 at the starting of view and change your form name as form1:

```
def getview(request):
  formObject = form_input()
  formObject.orign = None
  formObject.destinations = None
  formObject.timeWindow = None
  form1 = ro_input_form(request.POST)

  if request.method == 'POST':
     form1 = ro_input_form(request.POST)

     if form1.is_valid():

        form1.save()

        return HttpResponse(status=200)
  else:

     form1 = ro_input_form()  ## this should be forminput

return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

Comment: I'm not encountering any errors as for now but its not saving my data in database

Comment: you can just use form.save() after is valid() and it will save the data as of my edited answer.